# Android: How to communicate and exchange objects with a Local Service?

Tags: android, json, http, android-service

So far I've a class for a simple local service. What I want to do is to **send requests** to this local service **from different activies** in my application. Depending on the parameters of these requests the service will connect via HttpClient to a webserver and receive a JSONObject and return it to the activity. All the HTTP communication is already working within my activity, but I'd like it to **run in a separate thread in my local service** now.

The source code of my very simple local service looks like this so far:

```
// BackgroundService.java
package com.test.localservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
public class BackgroundService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("BackgroundService", "onCreate()");
        Thread thr = new Thread(null, new RunThread(), "BackgroundService");
        thr.start();
    }
    class RunThread implements Runnable
    {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("BackgroundService", "run()");

            /* Here the HTTP JSON communication is going to happen */

            //BackgroundService.this.stopSelf();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.i("BackgroundService", "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.i("BackgroundService", "onStart()");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("BackgroundService", "onBind()");
        return null;
    }

}
```

The problem I'm facing now (due to a lack of knowledge) is the communication part **Activities <--> Local Service**. I found some communication and object exchange examples for a **Remote Service** using [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) (Android Interface Definiton Language). However, I'm not sure if I've to go this path. I would simply like to exchange either my own defined objects or if that is not possible then just a JSONObject or if it makes things much easier even just simple String Arrays would work (for now).

Can someone please point me in the right direction and if possible give a simple example of an Object exchange (both ways) with a local service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using an `AsyncTask` instead of your own thread in this scenario.

To give an activity a reference to your `BackgroundService` object, your options are:

1. Use a singleton (i.e., make your `BackgroundService` object available from a static context, such as a public static data member, nulling out that static reference in `onDestroy()`).
2. Follow the `LocalServiceBinding` API sample to return an `IBinder` that simply gives access to the `BackgroundService` object.

From there, everything is in the same JVM, so you can just pass objects around. Be careful, though, not to hold onto anything past the component lifetime (e.g., `Activity` should not cache the singleton).

Comment: Thanks. The LocalServiceBinding API sample actually helped a lot. Also AsyncTask was a great hint. For those who need help with threading on Android here's a good blog post from the dev team: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html